# How can I see when package has been upgraded?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, crunchbang

Is there a way to see the upgrade history with date with some program e.g. apt? I want to know when exactly I upgraded security relevant packages the last time and the time before that...
Thanks a lot!
**Edit:**
My bad. Forgot to mention that I am using Crunchbang waldorf. Sorry.

Comment: What OS are you using? Ubuntu?

Comment: No Crunchbang. Sorry, forgot to write that

Comment: Similar - http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12578/4671. These kinds of questions have been asked before, and some of them should probably be closed as dupes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `apt` history is usually kept in `/var/log/apt`. You should be able to view the most recent log with:

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Older log files may be compressed, so you may need:

```
zless /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
```

Also see the `term.log` files for the output that was on the terminal.